# What is the battery difference between Nintendo Switch and Nintendo Switch Oled?

Tags: version-differences, nintendo-switch

So, I was watching some Switch OLED videos on YouTube and the only thing they didn't cover was the battery life between OLED and regular model. Does anyone know the difference  between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite having new CPU and RAM, Switch OLED has **the same 4310mAh Lithium-ion** power cell that's seen in the original Switch model.

Switch OLED uses an OLED screen rather than an LCD one, it's actually using less power – so the increased screen size is balanced out by the less-hungry display technology.

This is presumably why Nintendo has listed the exact same approximate battery life for the OLED Model as the 2019 'XKW' version: **4.5 to 9 hours**, depending on the game being played.

You can find more information [here](https://www.nintendolife.com/guides/switch-oled-battery-life-how-does-it-compare-to-the-switch-and-switch-lite).